# Surface integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

Without getting into the whole question, I was asked to evaluate a surface integral

$\iint\limits_S f(x,y,z) da$

where S is the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = x$ 
between $z=a$ and $z=b$

Now normally I would parametize this as a cylinder and it would be easy peasy but I'm worried about the equation of the cylinder,  as my normal equation would be more like $x^2 + y^2 = C$ with C being some constant .. Any thoughts ? thanks a lot

Comment: $x^2+y^2=x$ is the equation of a circle, get center and radius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your cylinder is offset from the axis.  $x^2+y^2=x$ becomes $(x-\frac 12)^2+y^2=\frac 14$.  You can substitute $u=x-\frac 12$ to get back on axis if you want.

Comment: thanks boss .. concise and complete :)